# How to Grab records from an object

Tags: java, file, object, serialization

I am having a very difficult time on figuring out how to get records from an object that i have passed in the path to the file.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import edu.trident.cpt237.recordreaper.CabRecordReaper;

public class CabOrginazer implements CabInfo
{


private final String FARE = "";
private final String GAS = "";
private final String SERVICE = "";
private final String MILES = "";
private final double VALUE = 0.0;
CabRecordReaper reaper = new CabRecordReaper("C:/CabRecords/September.txt" );


public void cabOrginazer()
{

}

@Override
public Records getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String CabId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public double getValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public double getPerGallonCost() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

I have try'd using a Scanner but does not work so i took it out. I can't do any of my other methods until i can grab what is in side of that reaper. The only methods inside of the CabRecordReaper is hasMoreRecord() which determines if there is more lines in the file.

Comment: Check what hasMoreRecord() returns. If it returns a record, then that record may have methods that will let you access the properties.

Comment: @Susie What hasMoreRecord() returns is a boolean

Comment: Please show what CabRecordReaper class contains.

Comment: @Susie I can't show what CaRecordReaper contains inside because it is in a jar and does not have the source path and i don't have that. But i can see what is inside of CaRecordReaper hasMoreRecords() that returns a boolean. addRecordFromLine(String) that is a void. CabRecordReaper(String) this is the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understanding your question but I think you are having difficulties with reading from a .txt file?

```
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path here")) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Add your code here.
            System.out.println(true);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have also try'd that but that did not work. It can't grab the path to the file from the object reaper. Reading from the text file is what i am try'n to do. But i have to do it from the object reaper and that is where the problem is.